# How to invoke ant task in python script?

Tags: python, ant

I know we can call like this:

```
os.system("ant compile")
```

But how to know whether the ant task is successful or not?

And is there another way to invoke ant task?

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846025/python-get-the-return-code-of-ant-sub-process-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify ant to return a success code and capture that in python in it's return?

http://www.dotkam.com/2008/10/24/getting-return-code-from-ant-in-shell/

Comment: it's a good and helpful article, but I want to get the return code from ant in python script instead of SHELL

Comment: Return it to the Shell, then take that into python  : http://pydanny.blogspot.com/2007/11/capturing-shell-output-in-python.html

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess
p1 = subprocess.Popen('ant compile', stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
print p1.stdout.read(-1)
print p1.stdin.read(-1)
print p1.stderr.read(-1)
```

Try using subprocess to get the output/error.....

Answer (score 1):

`os.system` returns a return code.  So you can just capture it and check it.

```
rc = os.system("ant compile")
if rc != 0: 
   print "Error on ant compile"
   sys.exit(1)
```